# Sending a Checkbox to Specific URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

For example; if a user clicks pop and rock boxes i want to send the page to `www.mysite.com/?view=listen&tag[]=pop&tag[]=rock`
If i use form code below it works on Firefox and IE fine. But if user clicks with Google Chrome, page goes to `http://www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com/?view=listen&tag[0]pop&tag[1]rock&`  equal signs in front of tag names disappear. How can i get worked on google Chrome too?

```
<form action="http://www.mysite.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="listen" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="pop" />pop<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="rock" />rock<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="indie" />indie<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="electronic" />electronic<br />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this. In google chrome, it does post the form to correct url with square brackets and equal sign:

Here is your code:

Form URL: http://jsbin.com/ihagon/1

When I select pop and rock and press submit, it goes to this url:

Target URL: http://jsbin.com/ihagon/1?view=listen&tag%5B%5D=pop&tag%5B%5D=rock

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <form action="http://jsbin.com/ihagon/1">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="listen" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="pop" />pop<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="rock" />rock<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="indie" />indie<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="electronic" />electronic<br />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I have realised that i left open a useless javascript function. So this is the problem's source.